# Can I change my workflow from Managed to Bare in React native after I've started my project?

Tags: react-native, workflow

I was wondering if I can change my workflow from Managed to Bare in React native after I've started my project ?

If so, what are the consequences ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using Expo-CLI (and not react-native cli), you can, of course `expo eject` your project to change from manage workflow, to bare one.

Here is the documentation : https://docs.expo.io/bare/exploring-bare-workflow/